# Image swap on image click with javascript if else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to swap an image on a click with javascript if else method. The first image swap works(if), but the other 2 dont(else if). Here is my JS/JQuery:

```
$("#right").on("click" , 

 function() {

    var pic = $("#selection img").attr("id");

    if (pic == "instagram") {
        $("#instagram").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
        $("#snapchat").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
        $("span").text("Snapchat");

    }

    else if (pic == "snapchat") {
        $("#snapchat").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
        $("#twitter").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
        $("span").text("Twitter");
    }

    else if (pic == "twitter") {
        $("#twitter").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
        $("#facebook").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
        $("span").text("Facebook");
    }

});
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.hide {
display: none;
}

.show {
display: inline;
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div id="selection">
    <img id="instagram" class="show" src="img/instagram.png">
    <img id="snapchat" src="img/snapchat.png">
    <img id="twitter" src="img/twitter.png">
    <img id="facebook" src="img/facebook.png">
</div>
```

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: Andy : Do you want to show one image at time ? and then next next next, is it ? what is #right ?

Comment: Hello, yes i want to show one image at the time and then next next next. #right is an arrow svg file.

Comment: Go log the value of `pic` to console, and be surprised.

Comment: Yeah @CBroe, I updated my answer with that about a minute before you posted it, hahaha.

Comment: @AndyMac Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39676451/6608101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to swap the classes between the indexes of the image.

This is considered as cycle, if your on the last index then it should start with first then.

Check the working snippet.

```js
//Apply the hide to all the images except first one
$('#selection img').not(":eq(0)").addClass("hide");
var currentIndex=0;
var newIndex=0;
$("#right").on("click" , function() {
  //Check is it a last index
  var isLast = $('#selection img').last().hasClass('show');
  currentIndex = $('#selection img.show').index();
  //If it is last index then hide the same and show the first image
  if(isLast)
  {
          $('#selection  img:eq('+currentIndex+')')
              .removeClass('show')
              .addClass('hide');

          $('#selection  img:eq(0)')
              .removeClass('hide')
              .addClass('show');
  }
  else
  {
          $('#selection  img:eq('+currentIndex+')')
               .removeClass('show')
               .addClass('hide');

          $('#selection img:eq('+(currentIndex+1)+')')
              .removeClass('hide')
              .addClass('show');  
  }
  $('#output').html($('#selection img.show').attr('id'));
});
```

```css
.hide {
display: none;
}

.show {
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selection">
    <img id="instagram" class="show" src="img/instagram.png">
    <img id="snapchat" src="img/snapchat.png">
    <img id="twitter" src="img/twitter.png">
    <img id="facebook" src="img/facebook.png">
</div>
<span id="output"></span>
<a href="#" id="right">Right</a>
```

Comment: Hello @loading.. It works flawlessy aswell. Where can i add the text chnage? so when instagram logo is show its says "instagram" & when snapchat logo is show it shows "snapchat". Also if you could update the snippet with a left arrow added. So its both sided. Thank you

Comment: @AndyMac : see it automatically gets the id of selected / shown image, considering as a text to shown.

Comment: i have text in a <p><span></span></p>

Comment: okay, I've taken span with id output, see the last line of javascript. You can make necessary changes there

Comment: It works! can you add the left arrow option? Thank you so much!

Comment: Try to make it from your side, You just need to reverse it from right, just try it, that will be learning curve for you. This is simple code based on the selected index of an element.

Comment: Ok will do. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Hello @loading.. i have been try for the past 3 hours to make it work on the left on aswell but i came to 2 problems: 1. only one image has a left option , 2.all images get hidden. If you could please update the snippet i would be very thankful. Thank you

Comment: Just update your question what your have done so far with your jsfiddle. So I can check

Answer (score 0):

maybe try somerthing like this:

```
$("#right").on("click" , function() {

      var pic = $("#selection img").attr("id");
      $("#selection img").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
      $("#selection #"+pic).removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
      $("span").text(pic);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

About to upload this to a fiddle! This should solve your problem.

```
$("#right").click(function() {
    var nextImg = $(".show").next();
    if ($(".show").attr("id") == "facebook") {
        nextImg = $("#instagram");
    }
    $(".show").addClass("hide");
    $(".show").removeClass("show");
    nextImg.addClass("show");
    nextImg.removeClass("hide");
});

$("#left").click(function() {
    var prevImg = $(".show").prev();
    if ($(".show").attr("id") == "instagram") {
        prevImg = $("#facebook");
    }
    $(".show").addClass("hide");
    $(".show").removeClass("show");
    prevImg.addClass("show");
    prevImg.removeClass("hide");
});
```

After looking at your question, it looks unsure what you're actually asking. Are you trying to create a gallery of some sort? Is there a reason the other siblings don't have `class="hide"`

If you haven't noticed your `pic` variable isn't equal to one image.

```
var pic = $("#selection img").attr("id");
```

What you're asking is "If the images in #selection have an id" (which is all of them) Maybe you meant

```
var pic = $("#selection img").hasClass("show");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/swvq6ves/ (old fiddle)

Here is the new fiddle including a previous button too!
https://jsfiddle.net/swvq6ves/1/

Comment: Thank you @conorReidd ! Works flawlesly! Appreciate the help :)

Comment: could you update the fiddle so it would work for the left arrow aswell? So it  goes back to previous pic. Like a image select option.

Comment: @AndyMac what happened if I am reached to last image, because it doesn't showing last image, and if I changed the id, it won't work.. So it's not a good way to code with text matching.

Comment: Hey Andy! I will update the fiddle so it does that now :) Loading.. if you check the fiddle I actually added that in there before you posted that comment. The Javascript just shows the solution for that one problem

Comment: My bad @Loading.. I miss understood what you meant. I've fixed that in the latest updated Fiddle! Thanks for mentioning

Comment: @ConorReidd still it's not a proper way to play with text, check my answer for more information.

Comment: By "Play with text" do you mean not using `id = "instagram"` and rather using `id = img.first().attr("id");` because it's more dynamic? This wasn't asked in the question **especially** as Andy's statements both involve using non-dynamic forms of swapping the images,